# Can't write to Qt5 textEdit box with ui->control->setText(message)

Tags: qt, qt5

I am trying to put the data passed to a mainwindow.cpp function on the screen with the typical 
ui->control->setText(message) without success.  The same line works if it is in a timer loop or a button function but not from display_that_data function

"MainWindow::display_that_data()" is called from myudp.cpp with the following lines

```
    MainWindow show_tlm;
    show_tlm.display_that_data(data_source, buf_copy);
```

mainwindow.cpp (updated to include emitting a signal for a SIGNAL/SLOT connection)
The SIGNAL/SLOT connection is set up in the constructor with the following line

```
    connect (this, SIGNAL (showdata_signal()), this, SLOT(showdata_slot()));



    void MainWindow::display_that_data(QByteArray data_source, QByteArray tlmBuf){
        QString msg ;
        msg = " in display_that_data";
        qDebug() << msg  ;
        ui->tlm_vals->setText(msg);
        //generate a signal which will trigger showdata_slot
        emit showdata_signal();
        msg = " in display_that_data after  emit showdata_signal()";
        qDebug() << msg  ;
    }

    void MainWindow::showdata_slot() {
        QString msg = "showdata_slot called";
        qDebug() << msg ;
        ui->tlm_vals->setText(msg);
    }
```

Runtime debug messages show that code is making it to the showdata_slot but it is still not writing to the ui->tlm_vals

" in display_that_data"
"showdata_slot called"
" in display_that_data after  emit showdata_signal()"

but.... neither one of the ui->tlm_vals->setText(msg) lines are putting text on the ui

---

"MainWindow::realtimeDataSlot()" is called by at timer timout signal as follows:

```
    void MainWindow::setupRealtimeDataDemo(QCustomPlot *customPlot) {
        // setup a timer that repeatedly calls MainWindow::realtimeDataSlot
        connect(&dataTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(realtimeDataSlot()));
        dataTimer.start(1000); 
    }

    void MainWindow::realtimeDataSlot(){
        QString temp = QString("%1").arg(epochTime, 10,  10, QChar('0'));
        ui->tlm_vals->setText(temp);
    }
```

And this works perfectly  (of course I have to disable it to see if showdata_slot is writing to the ui)

I thought the problem was a needed SIGNAL and SLOT connection to trigger the write to the ui but generating a SIGNAL/SLOT connection (which debug shows as working)  still does not write to the ui from the slot function.

For completeness mainwindow.h contains the following

```
    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();
        void setupRealtimeDataDemo(QCustomPlot *customPlot);
        void display_that_data (QByteArray data_source, QByteArray tlmBuf);
    private slots:
        void realtimeDataSlot();
        void showdata_slot();
    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
        QTimer dataTimer;
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: How are you calling this function? Could you please show that code also?

Comment: Original message updated to include additional code

Comment: Interesting finding....I created a new callback "on_tlm_vals_selectionChanged" from the GUI designer and put the same debug and ui->tlm_vals->setText(msg) in that callback.  

When triggerd by "ui->tlm_vals->selectAll()"  in a differnt function, the selectionChanged function still did not write to the ui.

When triggered by a mouse click in the textEdit the message DID get written to the ui.  So the very same function wrote to the ui if  the screen was physically clicked but NOT if triggered by an internal SIGNAL/SLOT call.

Comment: Is there something happening after the signal is emitted that's preventing Qt from returning to the event loop? If that's the case, the setText is working, but it's the painting that isn't because the event loop is blocked. That doesn't entirely make sense because it would seem that the timer and mouse click processing would also be blocked. After you call setText, use debug to display the results of "text". If the value is updated--and there's no other setText calls that might be blowing away your value--then it's a painting issue.

Comment: @goug I believe the loop is running as I saw something like app exec(), tried it in my code,   and it said the loop was already running.  I also have no reason to think anything is interfering as I set a string, send it to debug and send it to the ui... nothing in between.  It is strange but 100% consistent.  What seems particularly strange is that I am causing what should be the same signal in two ways.  One way is changing the selection by a mouse click, the other is by a code instruction which does a selectAll and both call the same callback function.... weird.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere deeply embedded in Qt there is a difference between gui mouse click generated event and code generated event and this somehow caues Qt behavior to vary with the same lines of code.  I will repost a more more "root level" question on this topic.